# C# webservice digesting json data to class

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I’m having a trouble figure out how to setup my web service to digest a json data variable.
I want to take the data being sent in a POST request and assigned it to class.

My function  (see below) the class is always null OrderReprint
So I’m missing a big step. Any help would be great.

```
 public Boolean Test(OrderReprint oreprints)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.seq1);
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.client);
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.Filename);
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.formcode);
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.jobnum);
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.userid);
        Debug.WriteLine(OrderReprints.seq1);
        return true;
    }
```

My  interface look like this

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             UriTemplate = "Test")]
        Boolean Test(OrderReprint oreprints);
```

My data contract class looks like this

```
 [DataContract]
public class OrderReprint
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Filename;
  [DataMember] 
  public string seq1;
  [DataMember]
  public string jobnum;
  [DataMember]
  public string formcode;
  [DataMember]
  public string userid;
  [DataMember]
  public string client;
}
```

My call Ajax call look like this:

```
$.ajax({

    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    dataType: "text",
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
}).then(function (data) {

    if (data.results) {
    /* (done something here*/
    }

}).fail(function (e) {

    errorAlert('Process Job', 'Error retriving job informaiton!');
});
```

Comment: Try this: `data: { oreprints: JSON.stringify(params) },`

Comment: Can you post sample JSON as well?

Comment: Can you post the DataContract code from the interface?

Comment: @Pawel: that did not work the call to the  method don't even get made any longer

Comment: @Stinky : {"Filename":"NEW73907","seq1":"1","jobnum":"3081969","formcode":"MML1","userid":1,"client":"MAILMERGE"}

Comment: @Aaron, I update my question to show the data contract it's the class I'm Trying to fill

Comment: Can add this before the **$.ajax** operation in your JS - ***alert("Input: " + JSON.stringify(params));***  Does this show your params in the proper JSON format?

Comment: @Mike Another idea would be this data: `JSON.stringify({ oreprints: params }),`

Comment: @Mike Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40011158/5501613) - model binder is case sensitive, so maybe there is something wrong with letter sizes

Comment: @PawełHemperek, hey did everything is correct. I have some more googling to do to see if I can figure this out, Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I removed the **BodyStyle** from the OperationContract and it worked!

`BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`,

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             UriTemplate = "Test")]
        bool Test(OrderReprint oreprints);
```

Thanks everyone for your help..

Comment: It should also work with Bare.  I just came back (sorry it took so long), and noticed that you had posted a sample JSON.  That's definitely a Bare request.

Comment: Not sure,  that's the only thing I changed? And it worked.

Comment: I believe Bare is default anyway, I don't think it'll change anything if you explicitly declare it.  Either way, glad you got it working :)

Comment: Aaron@  I'll look more into it but like you said it's working lol thanks for your help