# Can't pass data to asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ngresource

I have a problem, I need to send data from my Angular to my ASP.NET Core server. Here is controller:

```
[HttpPut]
public IActionResult setCoupon(int id, string CouponCode, int DiscountPercent)
{
    try
    {
        var coupon = new Coupon()
        {
            Id = id,
            CouponCode = CouponCode,
            DiscountPercent = DiscountPercent
        };
        return Ok(coupon);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return BadRequest("Wystąpił błąd");
    }
}
```

Here is factory from ngResource (getCoupon is working):

```
app.factory('couponApi',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource("/coupon/setCoupon",
            {},
            {
                getCoupon: {
                    method: "GET",
                    isArray: false
                },
                putCoupon: {
                    method: "PUT",
                    isArray: false,
                }
            });
    });
```

Here is usage of factory:

```
        $scope.addCouponCode = function(coupon) {
        couponApi.putCoupon(coupon);
    };
```

When i debug my asp.net server i found my params null or 0. I have the same problem on restangular library.

I also try this way to write controller method

```
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult setCoupon(Coupon coupon)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(coupon);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest("Wystąpił błąd");
        }
    }
```

My json which I try to send is this

```
{"id":1,"couponCode":"abc","discountPercent":10}
```

and my Echo method send me this:

```
{"id":0,"couponCode":null,"discountPercent":0}
```

**Update**

Apparently in asp.net core, method need to have attribute[FromBody]

```
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult setCoupon([FromBody] Coupon coupon)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(coupon);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest(new {errorMessage = "Wystąpił błąd"});
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Take a look to :https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api.

seems like you need to create a model for your request.!

Comment: I updated my post, i tried to do this this way, and i have a model, but still i am, getting null or 0

Comment: can you try sending {"Id":1,"CouponCode":"abc","DiscountPercent":10}. maybe is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

As Aldo says in the comments. The answer is C# expects case-sensitive matching of the json data.  So:

```
{"id":1,"couponCode":"abc","discountPercent":10}
```

needs to be:

```
{"id":1,"CouponCode":"abc","DiscountPercent":10}
```

You were getting a 0 for 'discountPercent' because that is the default value of the unmatched int, whereas null is the default for a unmatched string, hence Echo returns:

```
{"id":0,"couponCode":null,"discountPercent":0}
```

Comment: Sending this json:
'code' {"CouponCode":"abc","DiscountPercent":10,"Id":1} 'code'

Comment: Sending this json, didn't help. Im still getting null or zero.
{"CouponCode":"abc","DiscountPercent":10,"Id":1}

Comment: "id" needs to be lower case. Parameters need to match the casing of `setCoupon(int id, string CouponCode, int DiscountPercent)`